# Fun with matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization

I want to just generate a array like this:

```
a = [1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 ....]
%% or something like this 
a = [1 1 1 .. ktimes 2 2 2 ... ktimes .....]
```

Can this be done by a single line of code in MATLAB ? I believe several answers exist. No loops please.

Comment: This behaviour is equivalent to the `rep` function in `R`, which is a standard function.  It's unfortunate that MATLAB lacks this functionality built-in.  It's a very useful function.  All methods here (`kron`, `bsxfun`, `reshape`, `floor/ceil`) can also be found in the duplicate answer.  I'm not downplaying the effort taken here.  It was a very interesting discussion, but for canonical purposes, I have marked the above post as duplicate.

Comment: @rayryeng It's actually a good find!

Comment: @rayryeng I did not know about that. Should I delete my question ? I dont want to be downvoted. My poor rep :(

Comment: @roni - Absolutely not.  Leave it here.  You got some great answers from some of the best MATLAB bigs here.  I actually enjoyed the discussion and reading through the answers, even though I have seen them before.  I have upvoted all answers plus your post :)  However, I have marked it as a duplicate simply for canonical purposes.  This will also allow other readers to see that this functionality is integrated into other programming languages and platforms, but not MATLAB *(grumble)*... and that we should totally make a stink about it so that it can be (one day) a native function.

Comment: @rayryeng I knew there was a duplicate question... (actually, there are several). I was just too lazy to search for it, and answering was just too much fun!

Comment: @LuisMendo - lol no problem.  I knew exactly what to look for though, so I decided to do it.  BTW, I did love the discussion below and loved the banter that all of you were engaging in!

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, it was fun. You should have been here!

Comment: @LuisMendo - You all took away all of the possible and valid answers lol.  I couldn't provide any other new alternatives!

Answer (score 8):

With `reshape` and `repmat`

```
reshape(repmat([1:6],k,1),1,[])
```

With `bsxfun` -

```
reshape(bsxfun(@plus,[1:6],zeros(k,1)),1,[])
```

*On popular demand* with `floor` -

```
floor(1:1/k:6+(k-1)/k)
```

Comment: can this be done without using any complicated functions like repmat or reshape ? I was thinking more like using some kind of round ceil or floor functions ?

Comment: @roni `repmat` and `reshape` are very basic Matlab functions. They are not complicated at all!

Comment: I know still I wanted to just use like ceil floor and round. I mean we do generate a series by typing 1:100. So can't that simple statement be modified?

Comment: @roni Added floor version too.

Comment: @Divakar I liked your "It's actually quite boring" haha that made me laugh thanks for that.

Comment: @Benoit_11 haha yeah, well then it became it a bit challenging with the demand for using `round/floor/ceil`  :)

Comment: @Divakar thanks guys for giving me so many options. I just posted this for fun. I was wondering are there any more left ?

Comment: @roni Use `ceil` or `floor` versions, shift down or up by `0.5` and then use `round`  to complete the set of `floor/ceil/round` based approaches!

Answer (score 8):

Let `n = 6;` and `k = 2;`. Here are some alternatives:

```
kron(1:n,ones(1,k))
```

or

```
ceil(1/k:1/k:n)
```

or

```
double(uint64(1:n*k)/k)
```

Comment: @roni Are you serious? The first two were just input data! See edit

Comment: Well @roni here's your one-liner with `ceil`

Comment: @LuisMendo o sorry about that.... my bad. I upvoted your answer. Your ceil function looks really nice.

Comment: I would have gone straight the reshape/repmat way but the `ceil` method is definitely a nice trick. (_the `double(uint(...))` method is just about the same in disguise, you let the type casting take care of the `ceil` operation behind the scene_)

Comment: @Hoki I agree on both things. `repmat` is the way to go

Comment: haha it's sort of funny - You used `ceil`, so I was left with `floor` :)

Comment: @Divakar Yes :-) I liked your "on popular demand", very funny way to express it!